# cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/master': reference broken

Tags: laravel, git, github-pages

I am getting these error : fatal-index file corrupt when using git

so i use these command :

```
dl .git/index
git reset
```

now i am getting these error :

```
cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/master': reference broken
```

Answer (score 0):

Git stores refs and other Git data on disk under the .git folder, and it looks like the value of whatever origin/master entry Git was tracking is broken.

So Remove the file with command:

`rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master`

Then fetch whatever it can find from the remote:

`git fetch`

In final state, you should set up your branch to **origin/master**:

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`